# Process multiple file with Camel

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am a new at Camel. I want to process two specific file with camel with aggregator but i don't understand exactly how it work. I have to take 2 csv file with 2 different and specific name before proccess start.

Actually i use the route property "doneFileName" with this i can start a rout only when the "done" file are present, but with this solution some time i have some problem.

this is an exemple or route:

```
file.toWork.TEST = file:{{root.folder.TEST}}?charset=UTF-8&doneFileName=done&maxDepth=1&recursive=false&move={{done.folder}}/${header.coop}/${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd}/${date:now:HH_mm}/${file:name}&runLoggingLevel=TRACE\
          &moveFailed={{failed.folder}}/${header.coop}/${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd}/${date:now:HH_mm}/${file:name}&delay=5s&readLock=idempotent&idempotentRepository=#fileConsumerRepo&readLockRemoveOnCommit=true\&maxMessagesPerPoll=2&eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll=false&exclusiveReadLockStrategy=#genericFileExclusiveReadLockStrategyCustom&consumer.exceptionHandler=#volantinocamelExceptionHandler&include=.*(.csv)\&preMove={{inProgress.folder.TEST}}/${header.coop}/${file:name}
```

this is my fileServerCheckRouteBuilder

```
from("{{file.toWork.TEST}}").routeId("PollingFileComponent_FROM_TEST")
    .autoStartup(active)
    .threads(1, 1, "ThreadTest")
            .process(new FileLogProcessor())
            .process(new Processor() {
                
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    String[] coop = exchange.getMessage().getHeader("CamelFileParent",String.class).split(Pattern.quote(File.separator));
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader("coop", coop[coop.length-1]);
                    log.info("COOP: {}",coop[coop.length-1]);
                }
            })
              .log("reading file: ${header.CamelFileNameOnly} from folder ${header.CamelFileParent}")
              .to("direct:checkDoneFile").routeId("direct:checkDoneFile_TO_TEST");
```

and the my fileServerStartRouteBuilder

```
from("direct:checkDoneFile").routeId("direct:checkDoneFileFROM")

    .to("direct:executeCsvLoadLogic");

from("direct:executeCsvLoadLogic").routeId("direct:executeCsvLoadLogic").process(new FileLogProcessor())

    .choice()
    .when(header("CamelFileNameOnly").isEqualTo(FileName.FILE1.getFileName()))
    .bean(CsvReader.class, "FILE1")
    .unmarshal(bindyCsvFile1)
    .log("Reading of file ${header.CamelFileNameOnly} complete.")
    .process(new CsvWrapperProcessor(csvWrapper))
    .to("direct:writeToDatabase")
    .otherwise()
    .choice()
    .when(header("CamelFileNameOnly").isEqualTo(FileName.FILE2.getFileName()))
    .bean(CsvReader.class, "FILE2")
    .unmarshal(bindyCsvFile2)
    .process(new CsvWrapperProcessor(csvWrapper))
    .to("direct:writeToDatabase")
```

the "csvWrapper" is this class below and i use it to pass the both data to "writeToDatabase" route

```
public class CsvWrapper implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4967477652342694791L;
private List<FILE1> file1 = new ArrayList<>();
private List<FILE2> file2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

}

Someone can help for use the aggregation on this process?

- Read FILE1 and FILE2 (ex. FILE1.csv and FILE2.csv)
- Wait until they are both present and then start the
  "executeCsvLoadLogic"

If you need more detail ask,
very thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

When I understand your problem correct, you don't want to aggregate "whatever is currently present", but pick 2 specific files and combine them.

This is not the typical use case for the standard [Camel Aggregator](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/aggregate-eip.html). You might want to have a look at [Camel Poll Enrich](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/pollEnrich-eip.html) instead.

Poll Enrich is used to add specific additional data to the Camel Exchange by reading a file, doing a request etc. It is kind of a specialized aggregator.

Therefore you can use an [Aggregation strategy](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/aggregate-eip.html#_about_aggregationstrategy) to implement the "merge behavior" to combine the existing Camel message (before doing poll enrich) and the enrichment data.

Comment: Hi @burki, very thanks for reply to my question! 
In my case i need to poll 2 specific file, only when this 2 file are correctly load on the sftp server then i have to process it into 2 different class object with csvBindiny.
I try different way but it's not clear to me how it work the aggregation or in this case the poll enrich ( i see in the example only one file name how i can specify 2 name in the same root? ) can you show me an exemple fit my case? Thanks again

Comment: You would have to call Poll Enrich twice for the 2 files. And use an aggregation strategy to "merge" them into your message. For examples I would recommend the Camel unittests. Have a look at [this folder on github](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/core/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/processor/enricher)